# Creating a table in SQL Server using values of two table with some hard coded values

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

Creating a table in SQL Server using values of two table with some hard coded values.

I want to insert punchin and puchout for each `employee_code` which i will get from `[AttendanceCorrection].[dbo].[Tbl_FMOEmp]` and `Punch_Date` from `[Zultime].[dbo].[TIME_SHEET]`.

What I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl_EmpNotPunching
    SELECT 
        (SELECT [employee_Code] 
         FROM [AttendanceCorrection].[dbo].[Tbl_FMOEmp]) as employee_Code, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT [Punch_Date] 
         FROM [Zultime].[dbo].[TIME_SHEET]) as Punch_Date,
        '7:30' as PunchIN,
        '16:30' as punchOUT
```

Edit:

there are two different tables with no common values in it. One table contains `employeecode` and another contains punching date, now I want to create third table which will contain `employeecode`, punching date and puchin time at 7:30 and puchingout at 16:30 for all employee

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_FMOEmp]
(
    [Pin_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_EmpNotPunching]
(
    [Pin_Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [P_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IN1] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [OUT1] [nvarchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Can you copy table structures, please? We cannot help if we do not know the table fields. Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The non-standard `[..]` looks like SQL Server?

Comment: Why did you try an insert as select? Can't a simple `insert ... values (...)` be enough?

Comment: create two table ..

Comment: there are two different tables with no common values in it. one table contains employeecode and another contains Puching date, now i want to create third table which will contain employeecode, punching date and puchin time at 7:30 and puchingout at 16:30 for all employee??

Comment: table structure, CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_FMOEmp](
 [Pin_Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] ,CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_EmpNotPunching](
 [Pin_Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [P_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [IN1] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [OUT1] [nvarchar](10) NULL, 
) ON [PRIMARY]
one more table for date

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result. As is, it's hard to understand what you need to do

Comment: i am using sql server 2014

Comment: Sample data which i want SELECT [Pin_Code]
  FROM [AttendanceCorrection].[dbo].[Tbl_FMOEmp]
Pin_Code
21131
21334

SELECT 
distinct [P_Date] FROM 
[Zultime].[dbo].[TIME_SHEET]
2017-03-09 00:00:00.000
2017-03-10 00:00:00.000

SELECT [Pin_Code] ,[P_Date]  ,[PunchIN1]  ,[PunchOUT1]      
  FROM [AttendanceCorrection].[dbo].[Tbl_EmpNotPunching]

[Pin_Code] [P_Date]     [PunchIN1]    [PunchOUT1]      
21131       2017-03-09   7:30          16:30
21131       2017-03-10   7:30          16:30
21334       2017-03-09   7:30          16:30  
21334       2017-03-10   7:30          16:30

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your valuable time and effort i got my answer....
declare @P_Date table
(
  [P_Date] date
)
insert into @P_Date 
select distinct [P_Date]
FROM [Zultime].[dbo].[TIME_SHEET]
INSERT INTO Tbl_EmpNotPunching
select [Pin_Code], P_Date, '07:30' as PunchIN, '16:30' as punchOUT
FROM [AttendanceCorrection].[dbo].[Tbl_FMOEmp]
cross join @P_Date